# Saving multidemensional POST to database using PDO

Tags: php, arrays

I am learning how to use PDO and so far it's been going pretty good.
There has been 1 minor problem that I can't seem to fix.

I have an html form with 2 fields, but clicking on a `+` adds another 2 fields.

```
Array ( [domainname] => Array ( [0] => google [1] => facebook [2] => stackoverflow ) [domainextension] => Array ( [0] => nl [1] => eu [2] => com ) )
```

What I need is for this to be inserted into my database. Obviously "google" belongs to "nl" etc etc.

```
$post = $_POST;
try {
    // Create a new PDO object (start database connection)
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=domains', $user, $pass);

    // Build the query
    $sql = "INSERT INTO domain_list (name, ext, status)
            VALUES (:name,:ext,:status)";

    // Prepare the query
    $q = $dbh->prepare($sql);

    // Execute the query
    $q->execute(array(':name' => $name, 
                      ':ext' => $ext, 
                      ':status' => $status));

    // End the database connection connection
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

Status: this is just going to be the word "active", so I can use it to select.

I know I just need to create a foreach so all the rows get updated to the database, but I don't know the best way to do so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is this status thing?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'm gonna use it to select on the ones where status = inactive, so I can later set one to not be called without having to remove it from the database. PS: why remove the PDO tag?

Comment: Yep, you either do a foreach or you make a super long query. I don't think there's a more elegant way..

Comment: nowhere this status is defined - that's why I asked. How is this question related to PDO? Do you have any problem with PDO?

Comment: It's my first time ever using PDO, so I added it to the tags (in case there might be a PDO related solution). A moderator added the tag back in tho.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try something like:

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST['domainname']);$i++) {
  $name = $_POST['domainname'][$i];
  $ext = $_POST['domainextension'][$i];
  $status = $_POST['status'][$i]; //Since you have not provided what $status is, this is my guess
  $q->execute(array(':name' => $name, 
                      ':ext' => $ext, 
                      ':status' => $status));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than restructure the array on PHP I would just update how the inputs are created so that the name and extension are kept together:

```
<input name="domain[0][name]">
<input name="domaon[0][ext]">
<input name="domain[1][name]">
<input name="domaon[1][ext]">
```

Then you can just loop over the `$_POST["domain"]` array and use the `name`/`ext` properties themselves.

You could also use PHP's built in constructs for multiple array iteration:

```
$mit = new MultipleIterator;
$mit->attachIterator (new ArrayIterator ($_POST["domainname"]), "name");
$mit->attachIterator (new ArrayIterator ($_POST["domainext"]), "ext");
foreach ($mit as $domain) {
    // $domain["name"] / $domain["ext"]
}
```